# How to Persist Previous Events in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layers

I need it to build a specific Events Flow - for certain buy-buttons that refer to corresponding paywalls and success-pages in order to find out what buttons/paywalls are more efficient.

My website is an **SPA**. I use History Change triggers instead of Page View triggers (Old/New History State is what changes when surfing web pages).
There is a chain of actions:

1. Paywall-button click from a /page-1 to /subscription;
2. Paywall view (History) on a /subscription;
3. Authorisation (eg. on a Form Subscription event) on a /subscription;
4. Subscription-button click on a /subscription;
5. Subscription success on a /subscription/success (let's name it "Subscription Success 1").

However, there are other ways to reach /subscription/success (let's call it "Subscription Success 2"). For example, when step-1's click occurs on a big set of other pages (not /page-1)).

On the step-5, I made a special Tag that tracks "Subscription Success 1". It is based on a Trigger-group-1 that tracks success page's URL and a Paywall-button click from step-1.

So, in order to track "Subscription Success 2", I need to set up a Trigger exception on either Trigger-group-1 or on a Trigger that is responsible for Paywall-button click on the step-1. But it doesn't work like this: "Subscription Success 2" Tag fires anyway.

How to solve it? **How to persist that 1st step's event and use it as an exception**?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cookie that will save a value for the first event and then use the value as a trigger/exception for your tag.